# How do I change the units for measured distances in Google Maps on ChromeOS?

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os, google-maps

In the Google Maps app included with ChromeOS, the "Measure Distance" feature seems to always want to use miles no matter where you're at. How do you change this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On ChromeOS tablets, the units setting, which you can use to compensate for the automatic units feature not working for "Measure Distances", is there in the user settings the same way as it is on other platforms, it's just a bit difficult to find:

1. If you can't see the button bar at the bottom (the one with the choices "Explore", "Go", "Saved", "Contribute", and "Updates"), use the left arrow Back icon in the top left of the screen to get back to a screen where you can see the button bar
2. Tap "Explore" if it isn't already selected.
3. There is a search box in the top left of the screen. If you have a search in there tap the X icon to clear the search, so that you can see the circle user icon (with your profile picture if you have set one) at the right end of the search box.
4. Tap the circle user icon in the search box. This will show the user menu.
5. Tap "Settings" near the bottom of the menu.
6. Scroll down through the settings menu until you see "Distance Units" about half way down. By default it will show the setting "Automatic".  Tap on it.
7. In the dialog that appears, tap the units you want to use.
8. Use the left arrow Back icon in the top left of the screen to exit out of each of the menus.